# Special callbacks for apps from Google Now app chooser

Tags: android, google-now

I am writing a Calendar app and try to integrate it with Google Now. After phrase "Create event" Google Now initiate creation of calendar event.

[Event creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZycH8.png)

Also it allows to select app for event creation:

[Choosing app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCdSf.png)

Created event puts into user calendar and here the question: **what advantages gives app choosing? Are choosed app receives some special intents or activity callbacks?**

Manifest code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="2.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MaterialTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.SomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.OtherActivity"
            >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/event" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".NativeEventChangeReceiver">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED"/>
                <data android:scheme="content"/>
                <data android:host="com.android.calendar"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```